# Change make's working directory without long command line

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to change the working directory of a makefile.

(Extraneous info: I have a legacy makefile that I mostly want to reuse, though many targets and generated deps files make assume that the working directory will not be different. My idea is to create a makefile for my newer project, which is in a different directory, and include the old one, and set the working directory to the old directory.)

I easily can do this from the command line with

```
make -f /path/to/new/makefile -C /path/to/old/makefile
```

The users of this makefile would like not to type that out every time.

---

#### Attempt 1

Use `MAKEFLAGS` in the makefile itself. But neither of these seem to have any effect. (I understand why `-f` couldn't have an effect; I'm really wondering about `-C`.)

I've looked at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html, but I can't find anything about what is allowed in `MAKEFLAGS` and what isn't.

---

#### Attempt 2

Create a `makefile2` with the new targets

```
include path/to/old/makefile

foo: bar
```

and then `makefile` passes everything through

```
%:
    $(MAKE) -f $(abspath makefile2) -C path/to/old/makfele /$*
```

I don't get nice autocompletion, parallel jobs don't work, and debug options (dry run) doesn't work.

---

So

(1) Why doesn't `-C` work `MAKEFLAGS` (it does work, but I made a mistake; it doesn't work, and it is documented; it doesn't work, and it is not documented but it is intentional; it doesn't work, and it is a bug)?

(2) Is there a better way of change a makefile's working directory?

Comment: To summarize, you have a project X in a directory bar somewhere, and you want to call a Makefile from a project Y in a different directory foo somewhere else, do I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

Some things are wrong here :

```
make -f /path/to/new/makefile -C /path/to/old/makefile
```

The `-f` options specifies the name of the Makefile to be found when searched in the directory specified with `-C` (or the current directory if not provided). So it is more :

```
make -C /path/to/old/Makefile -f name_of_old_makefile
```

If the name is simply `Makefile` or `makefile`, there is no need to provide the `-f`option.

---

The `MAKEFLAGS` variable does not contains `-f` or `-C` in the called sub-Makefile.

---

To be able to pass multiple targets to another makefile, you need the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable.

---

Ultimately, all you have to do in your new Makefile is to have someting like this :

```
all:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) -C /path/to/old/Makefile -f old_Makefile_name $@

%:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) -C /path/to/old/Makefile -f old_Makefile_name $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```